# Why did Bootstrap make ".row"? Besides offsetting ".container"'s padding, is there any functionality that ".row" provides?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

If Bootstrap hadn't given padding to the ".container", then there would have been no need of ".row".
".row"'s negative margin offests ".container"'s padding.

Or are there any other reasons why ".row" is neccessay?

Comment: Which version of the bootstrap grid system are you referring to?

Comment: In < v4: `.row` apples the `clearfix` for the floated grid (which is very important in order to maintain proper heights).

Comment: v3! thanks :)
As you mentioned, `.row` applies all the properties that `.clearfix` applies.
Thanks again!

Comment: Thus the definition in [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) "Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns"